# doInBackground from AsyncTask never called when Service work on background

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service

```
private class Test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("test", "called1");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.d("test", "called2");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.d("test", "called3");
        }
    }
```

and output:

*test:called1*

Why other methods never don't called when Service work on background? If service stop, then all method calls and output:

*test:called1*

*test:called2*

*test:called3*

Comment: Where you starting this asynctask? How you starting service ?

Comment: Asynctask starting on Button Click, Service started wnen Activity Create.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you are testing on android 3.x or newer and you are simply affected by the change made to the way AsyncTask is executed.

This is how I handle this in my code to always work the same fully parallel:

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
    new Test().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    new Test().execute();
}
```

Basically change in AsyncTask appeared in Honeycomb (see Android SDK docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in "Order of execution" section), so before that, you launch it as usual, for HC and up, use `executeOnExecutor()` if you do not like new behaviour (noone does, I think)

Comment: Then this shall be solution to your problem. Just modify your code as shown in my example